# How to use exception template in phpstan

Tags: php, templates, exception, static-analysis, phpstan

How to use exceptions templates, for example:
there is some class throwing an exception

```
/**
 * @implements FooInterface<FooException>
 */
class Foo implements FooInterface
{
    /**
     * @throws FooException
     */
    public function exec(): void
    {
        throw new FooException();
    }
}
```

implements interface where exception as template

```
/**
 * @template E of Exception
 */
interface FooInterface
{
    /**
     * @throws E
     */
    public function exec(): void;
}
```

and i can`t use this template.
I get an error

> Method Test\FooWrapper::exec() throws checked exception E of Exception but it's missing from the PHPDoc @throws tag.
> in next code

```
/**
 * @template E of Exception
 * @implements FooInterface<E>
 */
readonly class FooWrapper implements FooInterface
{
    /**
     * @param FooInterface<E> $foo
     */
    public function __construct(
        private FooInterface $foo
    ) {}

    /**
     * @throws E
     */
    public function exec(): void
    {
        $this->foo->exec();
    }
}
```

Why is the exception missing if specified @throws E?
How explain to phpstan that exception depends on template?

Comment: Just open a bug report on PHPStan’s GitHub, thank you.